# LINQ group by and order by in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to convert my city list into group by state and order by city within it.

I tried below one but not able to get it right. Would appreciate any help on this.

```
cities.GroupBy(g => g.state).Select(o => o.OrderBy(c => c.cityname));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try below code

```
cities.GroupBy(g => g.state)
.Select(o =>new { 
          State = o.Key,
         Cities = o.OrderBy(c => c.cityname).Tolist()})
.Tolist();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cits.OrderBy(d => d.cityname).GroupBy(d => d.state).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

1 - Order by `cityname` first.

2 - Then group them according to `state`. Since you order first, groups are still ordered with respect to `cityname` property.

3 - Convert to single list. Otherwise, you will end up with list of groups.

Should work. I also advice using [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) notation for naming your variables.

Answer (score 3):

The `ToLookup` function may give you what you need.

```
cities.ToLookup(c => c.state, c => c.city);
```

This will create an `IGrouping<string, string>` where you can iterate through the `Key` values (states) and operate on a set of city values.

To sort it first, just do `cities.OrderBy(c => c.state).ThenBy(c => c.city)`.

Comment: Thanks John  for the inputs

Answer (score 2):

Do the orderby first:

```
cities.OrderBy(c=>c.cityname).GroupBy (c => c.state);
```

You might want to order the states to so.

```
cities.OrderBy(c=>c.cityname).GroupBy (c => c.state).OrderBy (g => g.Key);
```